# How to solve Circular import error in Python

Tags: python, import, fastapi, circular-dependency

I have this `User.py` class

```
from .Post import Post
from .Comment import *
from typing import List
import strawberry
from datetime import datetime
@strawberry.type
class User:
    id: str
    email: str
    username: str | None
    posts: List[Post]
    comments: List[Comment]
    createdAt: datetime
    updatedAt: datetime
```

and this is `Post.py` Class

```
from .User import *
import strawberry
from datetime import datetime
@strawberry.type
class Post:
    _id: str
    userId: str
    user: User | None  # Relationship
    content: str
    createdAt: datetime
    updatedAt: datetime
```

they are both in same folder, I have this error
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Post' from partially initialized module 'GraphQl.models.Post' (most likely due to a circular import) (U:\projets\grats-backend\GraphQl\models\Post.py)`

Someone suggested the `impot *`  can solve the issue but this was not really the case,
I appreiate any help, thank you

Comment: Any reason why `User` and `Post` aren't defined in the same module? Given the names, it sounds like you are following the very Java-like, but very un-Python-like, practice of defining one class per module. Java requires exactly one class per source file; Python does not.

Comment: `typing.List` is deprecated; unless you need to support Python 3.8 or earlier, just use `list`.

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff still cant do it idk what I am doing wrong, can you please fix it here https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-lF7UjN

Comment: @chepner ok I guess you are right, I ll try that.

Comment: moving them to same file solved the problem thank you @chepner much appreciated